# How to NOT send messages to DeadLetter in azure servicebus topics?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

If the processing of any message in a Topic Subscription fails, I want that message to be dropped from the queue and not send it to the Dead Letter subscription. Is there a way to do this ?

Is there an **azure cli** which can be used to purge messages from **DeadLetter Subscription**?

Comment: Do you want to constantly retry processing those messages or just want to delete them if a message fails to process?

Comment: Delete messages if they are failed to process.

Answer (score 1):

This would require some logic on your processor end. The code can determine if a message is about to be dead-lettered by looking at the system property `DeliveryCount` and evaluating it against the incoming queue/subscription's `MaxDeliveryCount` property.

Comment: I understand that...but I do not have a any control over the `processor`.

Comment: In that case messages will go into DLQ and you either have to write your own logic/script to purge. Or redirect all dead-lettered messages to a single queue and purge a single queue.